# What is the best way to display repeated codeblocks in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm quite new to asp.net and vb.net, so my apologies if I do not use the correct terminology here.

I have a database table and for each row in a returned dataset from that table I want to produce some HTML code eg:

```
<div>
    <img src="SOURCE" />
    <h1>Row1</h1>
    <input type="button" />
    <input type="button" />
</div
<div>
    <img src="SOURCE" />
    <h1>Row2</h1>
    <input type="button" />
    <input type="button" />
</div
```

What would be the best way to do this? Do I simply pull back an object with the entire data and then write a foreach loop to iterate through each row and insert a string to the page, or should I be looking to use a user control?

I guess I'm trying to make a sort of forum listing page and want to fetch all topics with a particular entry in a database and then display this list on a page with some input controls and an image. I also want to add pagination; so to show only 10 posts at any time and then be able to paginate to the next page.

Again I apologise if I've not been very clear, but I'm having a little bit of a hard time understanding the best way to tackle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

```
   <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <img src="SOURCE" />
          <h1>Row<%# Container.ItemIndex %></h1>
          <input type="button" />
          <input type="button" />
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: The repeater gives you must "customizable control".  The GridView and DataList are other options.  But I agree, the Repeater seems like the most likely candidate here.  Do NOT use "for each" and "Response.Write" !!!

Comment: Maybe show the code behind of :::: Repeater1.DataSource = myDataSet.SomeTable;  Repeater1.Databind();

Comment: Thank you @jrummell I'm going to have a read into the repeater. Would it be possible to explain a little what the user controls are used for, if not this reason?

Answer (score -2):

If you want any code block to be repeated. Try this code which i uses..

Sample code to display any div 3 times

```
<% For i as Integer = 1 To 3%>
 <div>
    <img src="SOURCE" />
    <h1>Row1</h1>
    <input type="button" />
    <input type="button" />  
</div> <% Next %>
```

Comment: That is not really asp.net.  That is "leftover" from the asp world.  I do not recommend.

Comment: @granadaCoder while some might think so, that's a common pattern used in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Ok.  I admit my MVC is not up to par.  Thanks for the tip.